# Android MediaPlayer : how to stop a thread before finishing activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-mediaplayer

I have created a mediplayer in android which has a runnable background thread for keeping the time seeker updated

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        long currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        // .... setting textviews of durations
           // ... converting milli to mm:ss and setProgress(progress)

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
```

and also I have a option menu in the main activity that on click should exit the activity

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.exitplayer)
            exitPlayer();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void exitPlayer() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        try {
            mUpdateTimeTask.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    this.finish();

    }
```

but it throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.getDuration(Native Method)

I know there is a problem in threading and should stop that thread before exiting activity but I don't know exactly how
can anyone help plz ?

Comment: try `mhandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask)`

Comment: did you try the above?

Comment: wow , Thanks , actually I tried it before but this time worked :D

Comment: what you mean by i you tried it before and not worked. Check my post and the link for the docs

Comment: before sending the question I tried this line but with removeCallbacksAndMessages(mUpdateTimeTask) that time caused another exception , but now it works and exits activity without ptoblem . thanks

Comment: ok check the docs you will get a clear picture and also mark the answer as accepted if it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the below

```
mhandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

```
public final void removeCallbacks (Runnable r)

Added in API level 1
Remove any pending posts of Runnable r that are in the message queue.
```

Comment: thanks it worked , sorry for my low reputations I cant vote up your answer